# Truffle installation

Tags: javascript, solidity, truffle

[][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5n57.png)Please I have been trying to install truffle using cmd and I keep getting an error, I even tried using the terminal in vscode and I still got thesame error message please I need help.
i tried installing truffle on my cmd using "npm install -g truffle".

Comment: You need to post code, not images, to stack overflow

Comment: all i just did was go on my cmd and wrote "npm install -g truffle"

Answer (score 0):

You must install nodejs which comes with npm first.

The command you are trying to use is **npm** and i feel like it is not installed.

Link

- https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: i have installed node.js but still not working

Comment: send error message

Comment: try using "npx truffle" to use ur commands instead of installing your truffle, for example use "npx truffle init" instead of using "truffle init"

Comment: that image i attached to the question was the error i got when i installed it

Comment: okk, i will try that now

Comment: i tried still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed npm with NodeJs and truffle properly. The error is about your file don't have a file extension and VS Code can't recognize your language. You have to type `npm init -y` in the terminal. Then, when you type `truffle init` and press Enter, truffle will create the necessary dev environment for you. Open the file explorer by pressing `Ctrl + B` and create a file named `MyContract.sol` in the `contracts` folder. You can now start writing code in Solidity. For more instructions follow [this](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/setting-up-a-node-project) guide.

**Note:** *Make sure you type the commands in the folder where you want to create your project.*

Or you can just create a file with `.sol` extension like `MyContract.sol` and write your code in it but you need to use `truffle` to compile and deploy your contract.

Comment: Ok thanks,,I’ll do that now